# Create Modified Instance of Immutable Derived Class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, immutability

Lets say I have an abstract base class and a number of immutable derived classes:

```
public abstract class Communication{
    private final String message;
    private final Medium medium;

    // getters, other methods, etc.

    public Communication(String message, Medium medium){
        this.message = message;
        this.medium = medium;
    }
}

public class HateMail extends Communication{
    public Hatemail(String message){
        super(message, Medium.Written);
    }
}

public class CasualGreeting extends Communication{
    public CasualGreeting(String message){
        super(message, Medium.Speech);
    }
}
```

What I would like is to do is "modify" a `Communication` in a similar fashion to a Java `String`, something like:

```
HateMail hateMail = new HateMail("I'm saying some really mean things.");
hateMail = hateMail.censor();
```

Where the new object returned from censor() is of the derived type rather than the base type.

Some ways I've thought of implementing this:

1.Using `Class.newInstance()`:

```
public abstract class Communication{
    private final String message;
    private final Medium medium;

    // getters, other methods, etc.

    public Communication(String message, Medium medium){
        this.message = message;
        this.medium = medium;
    }

    public <T extends Communication> T censor(){
        String censored = // Censorship logic

        Communication newComm = this.getClass().newInstance();
        newComm.message = censored;
        newComm.medium = this.medium;

        return (T) newComm;
    }
}
```

But this way is really terrible and I would have to implement no-argument constructors for all the derived classes.

2.Using `Class.getConstructors()`.  But this doesn't feel much better than the previous solution.

3.Have an abstract method in `Communication` that is overridden in each derived class that returns a properly cast instance of that class. But this feels like it really violates DRY since the methods would only differ in what class they return.

I feel like there must be an easier way of doing this using generics that I just don't know the syntax for.

Comment: Note: your derived classes aren't immutable, because they can be extended.

Answer (score 1):

In generally what you are trying to do is a bad idea and there's likely to be a better design that avoids the issue.

Let me explain.

If `censor` is a method that applies to every `Communication` then it should be a method in that class. However this now means that it should be applicable for any variable that is a `Communication` and, therefore, should be returning a `Communication`. This would allow, for example, a subclass to decide that censoring communication returns a different subclass. You might think that will never happen, until the time it does!

If, however, `censor` is applicable to only certain subclasses of `Communication` then it should be a method, suitably named, in each of those subclasses and return an object of that class.

For example, if we assume all communication is capable of being censored with a default of no censorship then you might have something like:

```
abstract class Communication {
    private final String message;
    private final Medium medium;

    protected Communication(String message, Medium medium) {
        this.message = message;
        this.medium = medium;
    }

    public Communication censor() {
        return this;
    }
}

class HateMail extends Communication {
    public HateMail(String message) {
        super(message, Medium.EMAIL);
    }

    @Override
    public Communication censor() {
        return new HateMail(toCensoredMessage(message));
    }
}

class Greeting extends Communication {
    public Greeting(String message) {
        super(message, Medium.SPEECH);
    }
}
```

Note that it is perfectly safe to return `this` by default in the `censor` method because your class is immutable. (Note that the code you posted in the question wouldn't compile because you are assigning values to final variables after calling `newInstance`).

I suspect your question is really hiding an entirely different problem: once the communication has been censored (and is, therefore, now a `Communication`), how do you call methods that you know are specific to the original subclass. My suggestion for that is consider a [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). That allows you to elegantly handle not knowing what the new class is without resorting to casting or reflection.

Comment: If the method returns a `Communication`, would that mean I would have to implement an `ArbitraryCommunication` class of some kind, since I can't instantiate a `Communication`?

Comment: @Lisum No. There's no problem returning an abstract class from a method. The object returned will be an instance of a subclass but you can treat it as though it was the abstract class.

Comment: But without creating an `ArbitraryCommunication` class of some kind, the only way to return an instance of a subclass with the correct `Medium` is to make a new instance of the calling class, which is the problem stated in the original question.

Comment: A `CasualGreeting` (or any `Communication` for that matter) could have a swear word in it. The default implementation of `censor()` should not be "do nothing". If every class is overriding `censor()`, doesn't this become almost identical to @Erwin's answer?

Comment: And yes, option 1 in the question won't compile; it would require "terrible" changes to the code.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need generics. A subclass is allowed to return a more narrow return type than that of the superclass.

You can write it like this - the shared censorship logic will be in the protected method `censored()` (apparently, the censorship logic can be defined generically for all Communication classes - if that's not the case, the `censored()` method should be defined in subclasses only:

```
public abstract class Communication{
    private final String message;
    private final Medium medium;

    // getters, other methods, etc.

    public Communication(String message, Medium medium){
        this.message = message;
        this.medium = medium;
    }

    protected String censored() {
        return // Censorship logic
    }

    public abstract Communication censor();
}

public class HateMail extends Communication{
    public HateMail(String message){
        super(message, Medium.Written);
    }

    public HateMail censor() {
        return new HateMail(censored());
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically option 3 in the question, then? This is similar to how I'm doing it currently, it just seems like there should be a better way, since the `censor()` method must be present in each derived class.

Comment: @Lisum Except that there is no DRY violation as it factors out the censoring into a separate method, and there is no need for generics while still having appropriate specific typing.